# Reasons why views are not appearing using ng-view with Angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Just finished the back-end and the angular-front-end for a new app, and am now developing angular views.

Right now, even the templateUrl for '/' is not appearing, and any other is either being redirected because of:

```
app.get('*', function (req, res) {
    res.redirect('/');  // CATCH_ALL redirect to '/' and serve index.html
});

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.sendfile('./public/index.html'); // load this, angular handles the rest
});
```

Or if I comment out that first .get '*', a message like this appears in the browser for any other templateUrl

> `Cannot GET /admin/createitem`

My controllers & services & appRoutes & app are called in index.html,

index.html also has `ng-controller="itemController"` defined, and `ng-app="itemsApp"`

and appRoutes.js looks like this (with more identically formatted .when):

```
angular.module('appRoutes', []).config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {

    $routeProvider

        // start page
        .when('/', {
            templateUrl: 'views/itemslist.html',
            controller: 'itemController'
        });

    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

}]);
```

Any suggestions as to where to look? Or how to test to find..

Comment: Do you have your node server set up to serve static files? If not, the browser won't be able to find your html templates.

Comment: @m59 Yeh, `app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));` Good recommendation though, thanks.. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Then wouldn't you need your templateUrl to be `public/views/itemslist.html`? Look at the network tab and see what response you're getting for that request.

Comment: @m59 haven't needed to before.. tried it though, even ./views/itemslist.html because is in public/js/appRoutes.js.. Am getting 404 for admin/createitem.. Though 200 OK for '/'.. Even so, no view!